# Asp .net MVC 4.0 | how can I post a HTML form using URL.Action to a secure page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, url.action

I have a HTML form on a page which is not running on the secure binding but I need to post this form to a secure page. Now issue I am facing is that my form data gets lost when I submit this form.
I am using following following code for the form:

```html
<form id="pdp-form" action="@Url.Action("action", "Controller")" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" value="" name="Size" id="pdp-size">
                <input type="hidden" value="" name="ProductId" id="pdp-code">
                <input type="hidden" name="Product" id="pdp-ProductName" value="Product Name">
                <input type="hidden" name="Category" id="pdp-Category" value="Category Name">
                <input type="hidden" value="buyID" name="ProdBuyId" id="ProdBuyId">
            </form>
```

How can I post my from on the secure page without loosing my data?

Note : Secure page where we are posting the form has both get and post methods.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what are you trying to do, but you're missing the submit button

```
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

---

```
<form role="form" action="@Url.Action("action", "Controller")" method="post">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="Size" id="pdp-size">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="ProductId" id="pdp-code">
<input type="hidden" name="Product" id="pdp-ProductName" value="Product Name">
<input type="hidden" name="Category" id="pdp-Category" value="Category Name">
<input type="hidden" value="buyID" name="ProdBuyId" id="ProdBuyId">

<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I am using Javascript to submit this form.